# Bounded cohomology and unitary representations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

On page 9 of Nicolas Monod's very nice ICM report "An invitation to bounded cohomology" ([https://egg.epfl.ch/~nmonod/articles/icm.pdf](https://egg.epfl.ch/%7Enmonod/articles/icm.pdf)), he mentions that bounded cohomology may be related to the problem of stability of unitary representations.

Given a topological group $G$, the data of first cohomology groups $H^{1}(G, \pi)$ with coefficients in an orthogonal representation $(\pi, \mathcal{H})$ of $G$ give information on the possible affine isometric actions of $G$ on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (see for instance Chapter $2$ of the book of Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette). As Monod describes, through the perspective of bounded cohomology, one is naturally led to study of $\epsilon$-*representations*, namely maps $\pi : G \rightarrow U(\mathcal{H})$ from $G$ to the unitary group of $\mathcal{H}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{g,h \in G} ||\pi(g)\pi(h) - \pi(gh)||_{\mathrm{op}} < \epsilon.
\end{align*} The stability question asks: For every $\delta > 0$, does there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ so that every $\epsilon$-representation of $G$ is $\delta$-close to a unitary representation (in the operator norm)?

Monod mentions that de la Harpe-Karoubi have answered this question (with appropriate continuity assumptions) in the case when $G$ is compact.

My question is: has progress been made on Problems $F$ and $F'$ listed on pages 9 and 10 of Monod's article, respectively? For completeness, I will copy them down here:

$\textbf{Problem F.}$ Can one reformulate in terms of bounded cohomology the problem of the stability of unitary representations?

$\textbf{Problem F'.}$ Prove or disprove: Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in a connected simple Lie group of real rank at least two, e.g. $\Gamma = \mathrm{SL}(3, \mathbb{Z})$. Then for every $\delta > 0$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that every $\epsilon$-representation of $\Gamma$ is $\delta$-close to a unitary representation.

Any comments / references are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think that https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.00476 can be helpful for state-of-the-art results on this subject

Comment: @Amitay thanks for the reference!